# Changing password for liferay default user 'test@liferay.com'

Tags: mysql, liferay-6

Trying to change `Liferay` password for default user using the following procedure as documented in http://blogs.aca-it.be/blogs/-/blogs/recovering-an-admin-password-in-liferay . The steps are as follows:

`1. Go to the user_ table in the database.
 2. Find the user you want to gain access to.
 3. Set the password_ field to some plain text password.
 4. Set the passwordEncrypted field to 0.
 5. Set the passwordReset field to 1.`

 `6. Restart Liferay
    Log in.`

Based on the above steps , I am executing the following command to change the password.

`mysql> update user_ set passwordEncrypted=0, password_='password', passwordReset=1 where userId=10196;`

After executing the above command , I started liferay and tried to login with the default user `'test@liferay.com'` using the new password , but the authentication is still failing.

Kindly suggest .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change password to '**test**' using sql:

```
UPDATE User_ SET password_='qUqP5cyxm6YcTAhz05Hph5gvu9M=' WHERE emailAddress='test@liferay.com';
```

Comment: Can you please add how you converted `test` to encrypted  text.

Comment: I didnt do it myself.I found it at blog long time ago.

Answer (score 7):

Just leaving an update for liferay 7 (as I landed here when searching a solution)

```
UPDATE
    User_
SET
    password_ = 'PASSWORD_IN_CLEAR_TEXT',
    passwordEncrypted = 0,
    passwordReset = 1
WHERE
    userId = USER_ID
;
```

From: https://www.e-systems.tech/blog/-/blogs/liferay-7-how-to-reset-user-password-in-database